# Strange values on Serial Monitor even with matched baud rate

Tags: serial, error

[image]

I am using the Adafruit Flora, connected with a Max 4466 microphone sensor. When I read values from the pin numbered 12 (which is marked as a11 for analog input on the schematic of the flora) I get random characters in the serial monitor as shown in the attached image, with my code. Trying to read other pins that are connected to nothing doesn't read any information. My baud rate in the serial monitor and the code are the same as you can see in the image.

Looking at the max 4466 explanation on the Adafruit website it says you don't need a capacitor or anything and can just directly plug the out pin on the MAX 4466 to the analog pin on an Arduino. I'm not sure if a different protocol has to be followed for a Flora instead of an Arduino. It also says to convert the information to an actual signal I need to use the FFT libraries, but I don't think this input being read is even correct.

If the FFT library is the problem here, I would need help on how to use it because there is no clear value being read in the example code. I had to set up a delay in the code otherwise the IDE would crash from all the info.Additionally, the VCC on the max is connected to 3.3V, the GND to GND, and the OUT to the #12 pin on the Flora.

Comment: Try to print "Hello World" and nothing else. Tell us the result.

Answer (score 4):

You can't concatenate string and value inside `Serial.println()`.

Print them using two different `Serial.println()`.

```
int pin12;
int A12 = A12;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  pin12 = analogRead(A11);

  Serial.print("pin 12 is ");
  Serial.println(pin12);

  delay(5000);
}
```